# How to access JSON in pl/sql endpoint which JSON is sent from a restapi post method?

Tags: json, rest, oracle-apex

Flutter code to call restapi for updating employee salary.

```
   try {
      final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      body: {
        'new_salary': 10000,
        'id': 123,
      },
    );
```

This is a pl/sql endpoint code for bind variables-

```
BEGIN
update employee set salary = :new_salary where emp_id = :id;
END;
```

[image]

I can use bind variable like this. This is when I need to change one employee's salary. When I need to update multiple employee's salary it's convenient to send a JSON with employee id and new salary. But I can't make the pl/sql which can make update the employee's data using JSON.

Restapi is called as follows in flutter-

```
try {
http.Response response = await http.post(
Uri.parse(url),
headers: <String, String>{
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
},
body: jsonEncode(requestData),
);
```

Suppose the json is-

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "new_salary": 50000
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "new_salary": 55000
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "new_salary": 60000
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "new_salary": 52000
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "new_salary": 58000
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is get the value of your bind variable and transform it into a json object and then loop through it.

I achieved this with the PLJSON library (https://github.com/pljson/pljson). I think it can also be done with APEX_JSON, but I haven't tried it.

For Example:

```
declare     
  obj    pljson;
  list   pljson_list;
begin
  /* blob_to_clob is a personal function that transforms the blob into clob */
  obj := pljson(blob_to_clob(:body)); 
  list := obj.get_pljson_list(pair_name => 'employees');
   
  for i in 1..list.count loop  
    /* your code here in which you obtain the 
       data from the different fields using the PLJON library  */
  end loop;
end;
```

For a single variable, you must keep in mind that PLJSON will have access to the content of the variable and not the name of the variable. For Example, if you do it like this:

```
obj := pljson(:EMPLOYESS); 
list := obj.get_pljson_list(pair_name => 'employees');
```

The json should be like this:

```
{  
  "employess": //bind variable that is used by oracle
  { 
    "employess": // the object that the PLJSON finds to build the list
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "new_salary": 50000
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "new_salary": 55000
      }
    ] 
  }
}
```